# How to connect MS Access database data to Net-beans java programme

Tags: java, database, ms-access, netbeans

I tried previous every method, to connect my db to my programmed

how can i connect my db in to java programmer
Plz sample code needed.... (I am beginner of coding)

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;


public class Dic extends javax.swing.JFrame {}
```

I wont to attached my access database and showing that data in to table

Please help me to do that correctly, if would you mind give the code for it
I appreciate
Thanks

Comment: We don't get pre-developed code here, we try to fix any issues that you might be facing. Try some tutorials for what you need and maybe learn for the future as well.

Comment: show effert and post code you've made or the bots will remove your question.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to download a copy of the [UCanAccess v4.0.4](https://sourceforge.net/projects/ucanaccess/files/UCanAccess-4.0.4-bin.zip/download) pure java JDBC Driver implementation for accessing Microsoft Access .mdb and .accdb database files.

This JDBC driver utilizes a couple other libraries like **Jackcess** as an MS Access Input/Output library and **HSQLDB** for synchronizing DBMS. All the required files come in the download. You just need to place these files in a safe place and add these libraries to your Project when you start one.

[Here is a good post from @GordThompson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21955257/4725875) to help you get started.